# Magento2 - Gender Required Error on Customer Login

Tags: magento2

We have an old customer's on the website who have not entered their gender when they signup in past. Now we have made Gender required for the signup on the website. Here the problem comes - when old customer trying to login to their account they couldn't able to log in. They are getting Error:- "Gender Required" when trying to login using correct username & password.

Note:- This problem is for only old customers who have not selected their gender.

Please find the screenshot for your reference. Need your help! please advise.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0va77.jpg)

Comment: It's cleary that your login code needs to be fixed, why are you checking if gender is given on login?

Comment: @PaulKaram i am not checking anything. It's Magento2 attribute validation issue. So if you have any experience on magento2 please provide the solution. Thanks

Comment: I was going to redirect you to their github issue mentioning this problem, but I see that you already posted your problem there too. I can't think of any solution other than setting the genders for all the unassigned genders manually. Each unassigned gender would be set to "Unspecified" (in case you can do that), and flag it as if the user has gave his gender.

Comment: @PaulKaram Thank you. I have updated the gender using MySQL query. Gender error message is gone. Now i am getting new Error- Please find the screenshot for your reference. prnt.sc/j7qpax

Answer (score 0):

Should run mysql query to update gender column to default value.

update customer_entity
Set gender = 3
Where gender = "" OR gender is NULL

Comment: Thank you @Nhut Vunhut - I have updated the gender using MySQL query. Gender error message is gone.

Now i am getting new Error- Please find the screenshot for your reference. https://prnt.sc/j7qpax

Comment: Login backend -> All Customers -> Edit each customer and enter value for customers which have empty zip code and city in address.

Comment: Another way: Write a script a update this if you have so many customers  who you cannot update them by manually